# MySQL Using LIKE, AND, OR together

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a search function that search for some pictures. Each picture has a state, that says if it is approved or rejected. The mysql checks for the state before returning, however it still returns images, that should not be returned.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Pictures
WHERE ImageTitle LIKE '%yaa%'
OR ImageDescription LIKE '%yaa%'
AND Approval='Approved'
Order BY DateTime DESC
```

"yaa" is the search for now. It's only an example.
The query returns a result that is marked as approved, but also a result marked as rejected. What is wrong with my query?

I've tried moving the AND statement to the start of the query, returns the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group your `OR` condition with parenthesis.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Pictures
WHERE (ImageTitle LIKE '%yaa%'
       OR ImageDescription LIKE '%yaa%')
       AND Approval='Approved'
Order BY DateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*There should be a parenthesis for 'or' condition, and the state condition should remain outside of the parenthesis*/
SELECT * FROM Pictures
WHERE (ImageTitle LIKE '%yaa%'
OR ImageDescription LIKE '%yaa%')
AND Approval='Approved'
Order BY DateTime DESC
```